# Xpages decimal and thousand separator for djNumberTextBox

Tags: xpages

I have go through the convert properties for an `<xe:djNumberTextBox>` element, but I didn't find the place to modify the decimal and the thousand.

```
<xe:djNumberTextBox id="djNumberTextBox1"
    value="#{Contr.txt_valcontrcv}">
    <xe:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber></xp:convertNumber>
    </xe:this.converter>
</xe:djNumberTextBox>
```

Currently, the result is: 159,999.00. I want the thousand operator to be `.` and the decimal one `,`.

Comment: I think it relates to locale set in browser.

Answer (score 0):

As always: have a look at the "All properties" pane because not everything is shown in the props tabs. You'll find a "locale" property in the "data, converter" section. Set this to your locale (I guess it's something middle european) and you're done.

For a DojoEditBox you may want to have a look at the Dojo docs regarding constrains/pattern: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/NumberTextBox.html#dijit-form-numbertextbox

Comment: I added my locale, but still it shows the value by default.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize that the Dojo stuff works differently, I updated my answer

Comment: I did it  If the document is editMode but I could not fix it If the document is readMode. :(